# Error: Provider configuration not present

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Im trying to update terraform version from 0.12 to 0.13. While updating the terraform I came across on an issue during plan

```
Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with
aws_sns_topic_subscription.sns_s3_raw_parquet_sqs_user_cleansing_monet_service_subscription
its original provider configuration at provider["registry.terraform.io/-/aws"]
is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in
the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
aws_sns_topic_subscription.sns_s3_raw_parquet_sqs_user_cleansing_monet_service_subscription,
after which you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have not proceeded with the migration to Terraform v.013 fully.

Make a backup of your current state with `terraform state pull` then try to execute the following:

```
terraform state replace-provider 'registry.terraform.io/-/aws' 'registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws'
```

This should amend your state to the newer Terraform version.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you'll have a `global.tf` file in your directory that lists some things that might not actually be resources. This is where you'd normally have a block like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "REGION"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

Looks like that block, whatever file it was in, got deleted. Add it back and then try again. Note you'll need to change `REGION` to whatever region you put your resources in. In lieu of access_key and secret_key, some people use a profile and put it in `~/.aws/credentials`.